# EditText adds special characters like @ at the start for RTL Locale

Tags: android, android-edittext, locale, arabic-support

I have an EditText set to textDirection - "Local" and trying it with the Arabic language. When I start typing it starts from the right which is what I want but when I type characters like "+" or "@" it adds it at the beginning of the text and moves it to the end after typing another character.
For example when I type rao@gmail.com, at the time of typing '@' and '.' the character is added to the start of the text.

I had a look online and read about using '‎' but was unable to get a solution, could you guide me on how I can fix it.

**EditText**

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password_text"
            android:text=""
            android:textDirection="locale"
            />
```

Comment: I managed to add a right to left support without any additional parameter and I haven't added the `android:textDirection="locale"` value

Comment: That is not possible. You might have added that support for your application in manifest I guess.

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: 21 is the minimum sdk

Answer (score 0):

In order to support RTL in the best way you should add this to your manifest:

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    ... >
        ...
 </application>
```

As said here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl

> android:supportsRtl 
>       Declares whether your application is willing to
>       support right-to-left (RTL) layouts. If set to true and
>       targetSdkVersion is set to 17 or higher, various RTL APIs will be
>       activated and used by the system so your app can display RTL layouts.
>       If set to false or if targetSdkVersion is set to 16 or lower, the RTL
>       APIs will be ignored or will have no effect and your app will behave
>       the same regardless of the layout direction associated to the user's
>       Locale choice (your layouts will always be left-to-right).
>
> The default value of this attribute is false.
>
> This attribute was added in API level 17.

Comment: You are not understanding the question. Rtl is working fine. But when I type special characters one @  it is adding the character to the begining of the edit text.

Comment: I understood that, but I thought that this will fix your issue. I have an app that supports RTL language and it doesn't have this problem. so I need to understand what I did that solved it.